# Can I Host php driven site on AWS Using Lightsail?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

Can we host a php site in [AWS Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/)?

I checked its feature but it shows wordpress joomla etc but not showing php.

Comment: Sure, its a VPS.. your get SSH access to whatever distro you install, then just install your servers/containers whatnot.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can we use Linux hosting for php?

Comment: Yeah sure, depending on what distro (OS) you install just google `install LAMP on [distro]` your find lots of resources.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. AWS Lightsail is a server that supports many things. The [feature](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/features/) you need is available and is called a "LAMP Stack":

> [LAMP stack](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack) is a popular open source web platform commonly used to run dynamic web sites and servers. It includes Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP/Python/Perl and is considered by many the platform of choice for development and deployment of high performance web applications which require a solid and reliable foundation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: @Yuri  can we use Linux hosting for php?

Comment: @Christian Yes, Linux and Windows + selected pre-configured installations are available.